# How to inject CUSTOM repository into my service?

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, doctrine, yaml, symfony-3.2

I have a custom Stats service, and I want to inject two custom repositories: booksRepository and reviewsRepository into it. How do I do this? When I use this yaml in services.yml, i get two regular repository classes (EntityRepository) instead of my custom repositories in the Stats service constructor.

```
AppBundle\Services\Stats:
    arguments:
          $booksRepository: '@AppBundle\Repository\BooksRepository'
          $reviewsRepository: '@AppBundle\Repository\ReviewsRepository'
    public: true

AppBundle\Repository\BooksRepository:
    class: AppBundle\Repository\BooksRepository
    factory: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", getRepository]
    arguments:
        - AppBundle\Entity\Books

AppBundle\Repository\ReviewsRepository:
    class: AppBundle\Repository\ReviewsRepository
    factory: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", getRepository]
    arguments:
        - AppBundle\Entity\Reviews
```

The entites have custom repositories set in annotations.

Comment: Your service definitions are fine.  The problem is with how you map your entity to the custom repository.  There are many questions on this.  Make sure you have cleared the cache and if you are using annotations, make sure you don't have any old mapping files lurking under Resources/config/doctrine.

Comment: By now, Cerad's comment clearly answers it.

Comment: @svgrafov - I don't mean to flog a dead horse but, with respect to your now deleted answer, you cannot directly instantiate an EntityRepository and expect it to work.  You must use the EntityManager::getRepository'entity name') factory method.  It's instructive to look at the source code to see why.  Hence the "just plain wrong" comment.

Comment: @Cerad I thought it was obvious that my repository class does not inherit from Doctrine's EntityRepository.

Comment: It should work. Does it work when getting your repo in a controller for example? `$this->get('AppBundle\Repository\BooksRepository')`

Comment: Thank you @cerad - the problem was caused by two .orm.xml files in Resources/config/doctrine that I forgot about and those two were overwriting the annotations setting for mapping.